# How can I toggle font size on click JavaScript / Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

There are 4 steps there:

1.) Click on category

2.) Show filtered products

3.) Select filtered products

4.) Display selected products in most right part of screen /3rd child component/

What I would like to achieve is next:

When I click on product (3rd step), product is added to 'right' component, and there I would like to change a font size of quantity so it might look like animation, like make font bigger for example 28 and make it small again for example 18.

Products are added to the 3rd component by using service which is shared between child components. This is how it looks :

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: Why did you remove all your code? This question and its answers are very confusing now :)

Comment: @ScottBeeson Ohh I did it accidentally I wanted to edited it cuz I'm still working on it, is it possible to back it up? or I need to paste code again? :S Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: Click the following link and rollback to the point you want: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51186494/revisions

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add a new rule to the `order-quantity-number` class:

```
transition: font-size 1s;
```

then define another selector in css:

```
.order-quantity-number.selected {
   font-size: 48px;
}
```

then basically you just need to add this 'selected' class to the span element and the font-size will be animated. After 1s (anim is completed), you need to remove the class from the element and the text will shrink. I hope it answers the question :)

**EDIT: Implementation details**

Template:

Add reference to the span element so that it is accessible from code

```
<span class="order-quantity-number" #ref>{{receiptItem.quantity}}</span>
```

ts:

Add the following line to the class to use 'ref' from the template.

```
@ViewChild('ref') elRef: ElementRef;
```

Add `setTimeout()` call to the click handler that triggers the animation to remove `selected` class after 1s:

```
onClick() {
    ...
    // 1. add 'selected' class to the span element
    this.elRef.nativeElement.classList.add('selected');

    // 2. remove it after 1s
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.elRef.nativeElement.classList.remove('selected');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: how can I know  that After 1s (anim is completed) so I can remove a class?

Comment: "transition: font-size 1s;" sets the transition of font-size to be 1 second long. so I would simply add a [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) call to the click handler, which removes the selected class from the span element after this 1 second.

Comment: let me know if you wanna see how to access the span element to be able to remove the class and i will extend the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple `@Directive` that implements `AfterViewInit` interface in which you will add a class with bigger `font-size` and then watch for event `transitionend` and remove class.

something like this

```
@Directive({
    selector: `[fontAnimation]`
})
export class FontAnimationDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(
        private hostElement: ElementRef
    ) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const el = this.hostElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
        el.classList.add('animate-font-size');
        el.addEventListener('animationend', (ev: TransitionEvent) => {
            if (ev.propertyName == 'font-size') {
                el.classList.remove('animation-font-size');
            }
        })
    }
}
```

> Warning:  `transitionend` will trigger event for every property that has transition, so we need to check if `propertyName` is equal to font-size.

All you need to do is create proper `css` class. Don't forget to import it to proper `NgModule`